# Dealing with Long running Tasks in Azure

Tags: azure, .net-core

We are moving an On-Premise solution into Azure and there are few services as part of the application which schedules to run once everyday.

I did it as a Web API and when ever the HTTP call calls the method fires without any trouble.

But the problem is the the method behind this API is a heavy weight one which takes around 40-50 mins to finish.

But since Azure APIs will expire in 230sec, I am really got stuck.

I am calling the API from Timer Triggered Azure functions. Its working fine.

But the 30-40 mins becoming a real challenge.

So how to handle this such situation in Azure when we have a time consuming method to execute.

(Other than APIs as well)

Answer (score 1):

There can be many issues that causing performance problems in Azure Functions. Try to debug with the help of [Azure Service Profiler](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/videos/exploring-the-azure-service-profiler/) or any other debugging tools, determine which line of code is executing how long.

Few reasons could be like:

1. There might be inefficient algorithm written form fetching IDs/ADLS (Azure Data Lake Storage) operations.
2. If `await` keyword is used in the Function App Code, then use the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` functionality also.
3. Enable `Automatic Scaling` in the Azure Function App..
4. It also depends on NuGet Packages that you're using which might be taking long time to create the Azure Functions instance.
5. `ReadIDs` and `ReadData` functions should be [asynchronous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Note: You may get doubt like all the functions are with `async`, but make sure in return type the Function definition should have `Task`  and `async` keyword.